# notify()/wait()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Если я не ошибаюсь метод `notify()` должен продолжать работу потока, у которого ранее был вызван метод `wait()`.

```
class Blocked {
    private int i = 1000;

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public synchronized void doWait() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Не " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            this.wait();
            System.out.println("сущностей " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++);
        System.out.println("сверх " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

public class RunnerOne  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blocked lock = new Blocked();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                lock.doWait();

            }}.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.setI(lock.getI());
            System.out.println("приумножай " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            lock.notify();
        }

        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.setI(lock.getI());
            System.out.println("необходимого " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                lock.wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е порядок выполнения программы в идеале такой:

1. Поток `main` запускает Thread-0, а тот запускает метод `doWait()`
2. Пишется "Не", снимается блокировка c объекта `lock` и поток останавливается.
3. Выполняется первый синхронизированный блок, пишется "приумножай " и вызывается метод `notify()`, после чего должен продолжить работу поток Thread-0, но этого не происходит и продолжает выполнять поток main. Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас происходит типичная гонка. Да, после того, как вы вызываете `lock.notify()`, поток Thread-0 готов продолжать выполнение. Но `notify()` всего лишь "будит" ждущий поток, и не дает гарантий, что "разбуженный" поток тут же продолжит выполнение. Поэтому получается, что два потока готовы работать (main и Thread-0), но какой поток первым продолжит выполнение и выведет сообщение, неизвестно! Если вы запустите приложение много раз, то иногда будете видеть и правильный порядок сообщений.

Можете поэкспериментировать и поставить задержку после первого блока `synchronized`:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.setI(lock.getI());
    System.out.println("приумножай " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    lock.notify();
}

Thread.sleep(50);
```

В таком сценарии у потока Thread-0 появляется больше шансов начать выполнение первым и вы будете видеть правильный вывод:

> Не Thread-0
>
> приумножай main
>
> сущностей Thread-0
>
> сверх Thread-0
>
> необходимого main